# Writing unicode data in python

Tags: python, csv, unicode

I have an xlsx file that I need to convert to csv, I used openpyxl module along with unicodecsv for this. My problem is that while writing some files I am getting some junk characters in output. Details below

One of my file has unicode code point **u'\xa0'** in it which corresponds to NON BREAK SPACE, but when converted to csv my file shows the **Â** instead of space. While printing the same data on console using Python GUI it prints perfectly without any **Â**. What am I doing wrong here? any help is appreciated.

Sample Code:

```
import unicodecsv
from openpyxl import load_workbook

xlsx_file=load_workbook('testfile.xlsx',use_iterators=True)
with open('test_utf.csv','wb') as open_file:
    csv_file=unicodecsv.writer(open_file)
    sheet=xls_file.get_active_sheet()
    for row in sheet.iter_rows():
        csv_file.writerow(cell.internal_value for cell in row)
```

P.S: The type of data written is Unicode.

Comment: Are you loading the csv back in microsoft excel? The handling of unicode in csv files is a little wonky. Excel by default usually expects csv data to be latin1

Comment: yes, I just tried opening it in Notepad++ and it shows space there, so does that mean the Â was a result of MS excel internal decoding?

Comment: Yes. It is normally windows codepage 1252. Before I answer, is this for your personal use or does it need to work for other people?

Comment: @Tim: Excel expects CSV data to be encoded in the currently configured codepage. That's a real pain.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I know, it has bitten me before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so what is going on is that Excel likes to assume that you are using the currently configured codepage. You have a couple of options:

- Write your data in that codepage. This requires however that you know
  which one your users will be using.
- Load the csv file using the "import data" menu option. If you are
  relying on your users to do this, don't. Most people will not be
  willing to do this.
- Use a different program that will accept unicode in csv by default,
  such as Libre Office.
- Add a BOM to the beginning of the file to get Excel to recognise utf-8. This may break in other programs.

Since this is for your personal use, if you are only ever going to use Excel, then appending a byte order marker to the beginning is probably the easiest solution.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft likes byte-order marks in its text files.  Even though a BOM doesn't make sense with UTF-8, it is used as a signature to let Excel know the file is encoded in UTF-8.

Make sure to generate your .csv as UTF-8 with BOM.  I created the following using Notepad++:

```
English,Chinese
American,美国人
Chinese,中国人
```

The result saved with BOM:

[image: Result with BOM]

The result without BOM:

[image: Result without BOM]

Comment: The problem with that is that a lot of (other) programs will choke on the BOM

Comment: @Tim: Not so much choke; the BOM is a valid zero-width space character. They may not particularly like that character if you are doing string matching against the first column without stripping.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Valid or not, I have seen a lot of programs that don't handle them correctly at all. Sometimes you even get them displayed erroneously as glyphs. Often these programs have mostly correct handling of utf-16 with a BOM or utf8 without a BOM. I would prefer bug free support everywhere obviously, but the last I checked (about a year ago admittedly) it still seems to be a common issue, and worth mentioning.

Comment: I haven't personally come across such programs, but I am not a fan of the way Microsoft has adopted the ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE for a UTF-8 BOM, which needs no byte order marker at all, either.